# Could an Opponent Remove a Patch from the Robe of Useful Items During a Grapple?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, grapple

My party has recently come into possession of a *Robe of Useful Items*, a magical garment which has patches resembling various...useful items. The patches can be pulled off of the robe in order to magically produce the item which the patch represents.

Some of these items like scrolls, daggers, and potions, could be useful in combat.

If an enemy were to grapple with the person wearing the robe, would it be possible for the enemy to pull one of the patches from the robe and use it against the wearer?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No.

> **While
>   wearing
>   the
>   robe**,
>   you
>   can
>   use
>   an
>   action
>   to
>   detach
>   one
>   of
>   the
>   patches,
>   causing
>   it
>   to
>   become
>   the
>   object
>   or
>   creature
>   it
>   represents.

So, to tear off one of the patches, your opponent would have to take the robe from you and wear it themselves.

Comment: And now you have me wondering how many Grapple checks you would have to win to undress someone and then put their robe on you lol....

Comment: That would make for an epically comic scene. A bunch of people fighting over a coat.

Comment: @Shane you forget the all important "fighting over a coat, only to wear it so they can remove patches from it"..... without context, this is indeed plain weird.

Comment: @Patrice Weird is Good :)

Comment: It would be interesting, though, to allow the enemy to still rip off patches. They wouldn't activate, but it would burn a patch the party could have used.

Comment: RAW I agree with this.  RAI....I'm not sure.  DM Fiat, I would let the grappler try.